# MSI not able to install service in a particular system

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer, gpo

I have created an MSI using WiX  installer for my service. But When I install the MSI, I can not see the service in service manager.
I tried  the commandd **sc query "ServiceName"** . It gives the message

```
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

I also checked that the user has permission to **log on as a service**. In other systems it's working fine all the systems have OS Version **Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]**

Comment: What were the results of the command *sc query "ServiceName"* on the 'bad' machine?  What OS version on that one?  What is the OS version of the system where its working fine?

Comment: @T-Heron I have added these informations.

Comment: So on bad machine, the MSI seems to install correctly, but when you go back in and check, you see message "The specified service does not exist as an installed service."  And on all other machines running same OS, they are fine, you see service correctly.  Do I got that right?

Comment: Can you post an MSI log of the install?